# Help with network on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking

So I have hp laptop where I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I'm in a location where I don't have a ethernet connection but I have wireless and usb connections from a gadget that basically works like a phone but it only provides 3G/4G internet through WiFi and usb. I have another computer that I can use to download files and transfer them to my laptop with Ubuntu. So I need help getting wireless network or internet through usb drivers to my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 using my laptop with windows 8.1. The wireless card I have is Broadcom BCM4311.

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) you'll find information on Braodcom wifi cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download this file on any other computer and transfer it by USB drive or similar to the Ubuntu computer: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-firmware-nonfree

Drop it on the desktop so we can find it. Now, on the Ubuntu computer, open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it is not installed, just proceed with the next steps:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should now be working.